# Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Tags: application-development, gradle

I just started with app development with flutter, but am not even able to run the test app. This is what come on console :

```
Launching lib/main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode... Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method) at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:225) at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:155) at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:169) at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:214) at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27) at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:74) at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48) at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65) at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48) at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128) at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61) [!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
```

I have active Internet connection. I also downloaded the gradle 6.4.1 and extracted it in android-studio >> plugins, This what is been shown on gradle-wrapper.properties :

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME distributionPath=wrapper/dists zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME zipStorePath=wrapper/dists distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip*
```

(i don't know what else needs to be done).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by opening gradle-wrapper.properties and changing the distributuion URL (in it changed the version from 5.6.2 to 6.4.1) .